# Programatically (Windows Service c#) Upload file to Microsoft One Drive without User Login?

Tags: file-upload, permissions, onedrive, office365api, onelogin

I would like to upload files to Microsoft One Drive using c# and shared to some of my friends on weekly basis.
I have tried few things but when using Authenticate API, browser shows login prompt.

So I would like to upload them without login, because I am uploading these files through Windows Service, which is running in background.

Please suggest the best way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need some user interaction to gain initial consent for your application to operate on the user's behalf, however as long as that process gives you a refresh token you'll be able to use that in your service to get current tokens without user interaction. It will eventually expire so you'll need a way to notify, and interact with, the user on occasion.

You'll need to ask for the `offline_access` scope to get the refresh token, see:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/getting-started/msa-oauth?view=odsp-graph-online#authentication-scopes